# Dependencies for Axis2 1.5.1 generated stubs

Tags: java, apache-axis, maven, dependencies

I have server side java stubs created with wsdl2java from axis2 1.5.1. I'm trying to integrate these stubs into the grander application, but I'm having a heck of a time getting the axis2 1.5.1 dependencies down.

Im using Maven2 to control dependencies. As of now I am loading most dependencies from a local library directory with all the jar/zip/... files for various dependencies. I have it all built into eclipse so I can see when the dependencies are resolved or not in the code.

The only jar files I could find on the axis2 site were axis2-1.2.jar and various other packages of the same version. I gave that jar file a shot and it did resolve a fair amount of errors, but many still remained (org.apache.axis2.databinding has several non-resolved references as well as org.apache.axiom).

I also tried using the axis2 1.5.1 pom as well, but that never seemed to resolve a single line of dependent code.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: does no one use axis2 classes outside of an axis2 server?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Maven to build server-side Axis2 code. Web services (.aar files) generated for Axis2 are designed to be deployed under the "services" subdirectory of the Axis2 web application. Each service will then leverage jars that exist on the web apps classloader.

The Axis2 project is built using ANT meaning it only has redimentary maven support (Module jars are published to Maven central). Version 1.5 changed these modules to reflect different logical groups of jars.

If it's any help, here is a [Groovy client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559074/steps-in-creating-a-web-service-using-axis2-the-client-code/2564323#2564323) that uses the Axis2 maven jars.

Comment: Yea I will end up having to use axis2 server and deploy it as a service. I'm assuming that axis2 server will auto-resolve its own dependencies for anything deployed in the services subdirectory. Previously my supervisor wanted me to build the server-side axis2 code into our own framework/backend as a service, but that was on the assumption that some kind of java library existed to provide a SOAP server abstracted from the rest of the code. The idea being we wanted to be running less applications (ours vs. ours and axis2). Oh well, easier for me.

Comment: If integration with existing Java is a project priority, perhaps you should look at some alternative frameworks like Apache CXF?

Axis2 is designed to operate like an mini-application server for web services. Indeed if you check out how the authors are using it in their commercial offerings the design origins of Axis2 become a little more obvious. (http://wso2.com/)

Answer (score 1):

We deploy axis2 web services, but we don't use maven.  Below is the fileset we use for packaging.  It contains all the jars an axis2 generated stub need to run.  All of these jars come with the axis2 distribution.

```
    <fileset id="axis2.server.fileset" dir="${dir.common.lib}/axis2">
        <include name="axis2-kernel-1.5.1.jar" />
        <include name="axis2-transport-http-1.5.1.jar" />
        <include name="axis2-transport-local-1.5.1.jar" />
        <include name="httpcore-4.0.jar" />
        <include name="axiom-api-1.2.8.jar" />
        <include name="axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar" />
        <include name="neethi-2.0.4.jar" />
        <include name="woden-api-1.0M8.jar" />
        <include name="XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar" />
        <include name="axis2-jaxws-1.5.1.jar" />
        <include name="axis2-adb-1.5.1.jar" />
        <include name="wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar" />
    </fileset>
```