# 400 Bad request when pass xml to webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I'm new in webservice.

I've to pass xml to aspx web service called plog.asmx

here is my code

```
String xmldata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + 
            "<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " + 
              "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " + 
              "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" >" +
              "<![CD[<soap:Body>" +
              "<SubmitJob xmlns=\"http://www.xdel.biz/XWS/\"> " +
              "<APIKey>"+ API_KEY +"</APIKey>" +
              "<Job>" +
               "<Customer_Name>"+ Customer_Name +"</Customer_Name>" +
               "<Address1>"+ Address1 +"</Address1>" +
                "<Address2>"+ Address2 +"</Address2>" +
                "<Postal_Code>"+ Postal_Code +"</Postal_Code>" +
                "<Phone_Number>"+ Phone_Number +"</Phone_Number>" +
                "<Mobile_Number>"+ Mobile_Number +"</Mobile_Number>" +
                "<Order_Reference>"+ Order_Reference +"</Order_Reference>" +
                "<Delivery_Instructions>"+ Delivery_Instructions +"</Delivery_Instructions>" +
              "</Job>]]>" +
            "</SubmitJob>" +
              "</soap:Body>]]>" +
              "</SOAP:Envelope>";

             System.out.println(xmldata); 


              try{
                  //Create socket
                  String hostname = "www.xdel.biz";
                  int port = 80;
                  InetAddress  addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);                    
                  Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);
                  System.out.println(sock.toString());                    

                  //Send header
                  String path = "/xws/plog.asmx";
                  BufferedWriter  wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                  // You can use "UTF8" for compatibility with the Microsoft virtual machine.
                  wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
                  wr.write("Host: www.xdel.biz\r\n");
                  wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n");
                  wr.write("Content-Length: " + xmldata.length() + "\r\n");                   
                  wr.write("SOAPAction: \"http://www.xdel.biz/XWS/SubmitJob\" \r\n");
                  wr.write("\r\n");

                  //Send data
                  wr.write(xmldata);
                  wr.flush();

                  System.out.println("1");

                  // Response
                  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                  String line;
                  while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                      System.out.println(line);
                  }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

when I run the code, I got error like this

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 09:37:12 GMT
>   Content-Length: 0

I googled the error and tried to fix but no solution come out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good ideia would be to use an API that implements SOAP webservice and is already tested.

I used this
[JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net)

400 Bad Request sometimes happens when you mismatch the protocol(SOAP or HTTP)

Comment: I don't wanna use JAX-WS. Is there any other solution? @fredcrs ..i

Comment: If there is no solution, how can I export my web service to another project ?

Comment: theres a good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463216/java-simple-soap-client

Answer (score 0):

It could be `<![CD[<soap:Body></soap:Body>]]>` try to use   `without ![CD[ ]] block`

Answer (score 0):

I already had "Bad Request" consuming a webservice. The thing is, after almost a day looking for an answer, we found out that was the size of the XML consumed, the size of the SOAP Message consumed. The problem is, the application that provides the Webservice to be consumed, must be set up to receive a large XML Data, we had to config our application server to expand to encrease the size of our buffer used to receive the SOAP Message from the client.

That was our expirence. I hope could helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with `HttpURLConnection`. Adding the below two properties resolved my  400 Bad Request issue:

1. `httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");`
2. `httpConn.setRequestProperty("soapAction", soapAction);`

Note: this error usually appears when you try to read response.

Comment: I need help, having this issue. Can you tell me how you are sending the SOAP Envelope