# Remote Web service

Tags: web-services

I am new to web services. I have a requirement in my project. They gave me a wsdl file and a web service link and document about the description of methods.

In the documentation there is method called `retriveDocuments` with request parameters *request, loginUser, loginPassword, systemId, maxResults, searchCriteria*.

They want me call webservice and get the required documents and show them in app.

My question is how do I call web service and how do I pass all these parameters and get the result?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: I am using Java, Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this a SOAP service.  Your programming language (such as Java) should have tools allowing you to generate a SOAP client for the service, using the WSDL.  Once you have the cient code, it should be easy to pass your parameters, make the call, and get the result.  There are lots of tutorials on the Web, but you can start researching from there.

Comment: Thank you so much Hew, Can you guide me how to create client in java?  I tried creating client from wsdl file by using web reference. But eclipse created client code with errors, I am unable to invoke the methods.

Comment: Have you looked at the related questions in Stack Overflow?  Offhand I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463216/java-simple-soap-client and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316776/what-methods-exist-to-auto-generate-java-client-stubs-from-wsdl-files.