# generating client jar from SOAP wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, apache, soap, ant

i am trying to interact with some SOAP web service which has the basic authentication and I have the url, username and password. Now I want to use this web service in my java code and so i need to create a jar file for it.

i have seen the below URLs but not sure if I followed it correctly. 
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#choosingclient
http://javasourcecodeetc.blogspot.com/2011/07/convert-wsdl-to-java-for-calling-soap.html

I have downloaded axis 2-1.6.2 from
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi (only binary distribution)

I have the client stub which was given ... I see people saying to use it with build.xml, but i couldn't find build.xml anywhere .... Please tell me what all i need to install to set up apache axis and ant ? What is ant doing here?

Answer (score 12):

**Mark's answer works, but I'm more of a Maven guy and want to eventually mavenize the output jar.**

Here's how to do it with Maven.

1. Download a WSDL to a directory (e.g. `mydir/MyWsdl.wsdl`).
2. Create a `pom.xml` file (as shown below).
3. Run `mvn package`.

Here's what you'll end up with

```
└── mydir
    ├── MyWsdl.wsdl
    ├── pom.xml
    └── target (add this dir to .gitignore)
        ├── generated-sources
        ├── mywsdl-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        ├── mywsdl-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
        └── mywsdl-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
```

And the source of the `pom.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>mywsdl</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>My WSDL client</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Generates JAVA source files from the WSDL -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <packageName>com.example</packageName>
              <wsdlFile>MyWsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
              <!-- TODO: Update this file with new WSDL versions -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
      <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
      <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: I can't edit because it would be less than 6 characters, but there is a missing x in the first line of the pom.xml:  "x"mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.....

Answer (score 7):

Axis2 supports several ways to support Web service clients. The most common approach is documented [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html#createclients) and involved generating Java code that parse the SOAP message described by the WSDL file.

The following answer describes a number of ways to invoke a web service. The last part describes a groovy script that uses the classes generated by Axis2 and compiled using ANT:

- [Steps in creating a web service using Axis2 - The client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559074/steps-in-creating-a-web-service-using-axis2-the-client-code/2564323#2564323)

## More detail

The wsdl2java program (bundled with Axis2) will generate an ANT project based on the specified WSDL file:

```
$AXIS2_HOME/bin/wsdl2java.sh -d adb -s -o mydir -uri http://www.xmlme.com/WSShakespeare.asmx?WSDL
```

This will generate the following files:

```
└── mydir
    ├── build.xml
    └── src
        └── com
            └── xmlme
                └── webservices
                    └── ShakespeareStub.java
```

If you check the generated java code you'll discover java classes that match the XML schema types defined in the WSDL file, making it simpler to serialize and deserialize SOAP messages.

The "build.xml" file contains the logic that will compile the generated java code.

```
cd mydir
ant
```

When the build runs it will by default create jar file as follows:

```
└── mydir
    ├── build
    │   ├── classes
    │   │   └── ..
    │   │       ..
    │   └── lib
    │       └── Shakespeare-test-client.jar
    ├── build.xml
    └── src
        └── com
            └── xmlme
                └── webservices
                    └── ShakespeareStub.java
```

This jar file can now be included by a java (or see my example groovy script in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559074/steps-in-creating-a-web-service-using-axis2-the-client-code/2564323#2564323)) that wishes to access the webservice.