# What jars are required to run Axis2 v. 1.6.2 generated client with JRE 5/6?

Tags: java, jar, apache-axis

What jars from **Axis2** distribution (version **1.6.2**) are required to run generated WebService client?

There are several jars in library folder of binary distribution, but with no notice, which of them are required, and under which circumstances? The answer [What's the minimum classpath for an Axis2 client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320178/whats-the-minimum-classpath-for-an-axis2-client/3581131#3581131) is outdated - it is about version 1.5, and the question itself is about version 1.4.

So which jars from 1.6.2 distributions are:

- required under Java 1.6 and above?
- required additionally for Java 1.5
- optional, only when using specific features?

Answer (score 6):

For our Axis2 clients, we include these jars.  We use JDK 1.7, so you might need more than this for JDK 1.5.  You also might need other jars depending on which binding you use (we use xmlbeans).

```
axiom-api-1.2.13.jar
axiom-impl-1.2.13.jar
axis2-adb-1.6.2.jar
axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar
axis2-transport-local-1.6.2.jar
axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar
axis2-xmlbeans-1.6.2.jar
httpcore-4.0.jar
neethi-3.0.2.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, for the answer to this you'd look at the [Axis2 WAR distribution](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html#servlet_container). It's a WAR file that you can download (or build yourself). It's all ready to be deployed within Tomcat or another web application container.

In principle, you can deploy Axis2.war within tomcat once, then deploy individual AAR files (Axis2 services) within the Axis2 environment. Accordingly, axis2.war just provides the Axis2 runtime environment.