# Axis2 migration error DOCTYPE is not allowed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7, weblogic, apache-axis

**Used versions:**
Tomcat 7
jre 6

I created a new dynamic web project and I added axis2 web service client in this new project. Then I turned this project into a jar file. 
When I exported, I only selected src file. And I added this jar file and the minimum jars for the axis2 client.
this minimum jars:
[What's the minimum classpath for an Axis2 client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320178/whats-the-minimum-classpath-for-an-axis2-client)

I run this main project and the project doesn't give any errors. But This project deploy
But when I deploy this project to the weblogic server, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:347)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    at webmethods.wsdls.universitebirim.universitebirimv1.UniversiteBirimv1Stub.iDdenBirimAdiGetir(UniversiteBirimv1Stub.java:494)
    at webmethods.wsdls.universitebirim.universitebirimv1.TestWebServis.birimGetirv1(TestWebServis.java:15)
    at dao.SozMaasDAO.ogrenimSuresiGetir(SozMaasDAO.java:1159)
    at dao.SozMaasDAO.ogrenimDurumRowSelect(SozMaasDAO.java:1192)
    at bus.SozMaasBUS.listYoktenMezunBilgisiGetir(SozMaasBUS.java:7622)
    at bus.SozMaasBUS$$FastClassByCGLIB$$41cbd8aa.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
    at bus.SozMaasBUS$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$aa66edae.listYoktenMezunBilgisiGetir(<generated>)
    at view.SozMaasView.hnd_yoktenMezunBilgisiGetir(SozMaasView.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:473)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at filter.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1499)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.DeferredParsingException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreParentNodeSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreParentNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreParentNode$buildNext(CoreParentNodeSupport.aj:96)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.buildNext(OMDocumentImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreParentNodeSupport.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreParentNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreParentNode$buildNext(CoreParentNodeSupport.aj)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreChildNodeSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNode$coreGetNextSibling(CoreChildNodeSupport.aj:115)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.coreGetNextSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreChildNodeSupport.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNodeSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreChildNode$coreGetNextSibling(CoreChildNodeSupport.aj)
    at org.apache.axiom.core.CoreDocumentSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreDocumentSupport$org_apache_axiom_core_CoreDocument$coreGetDocumentElement(CoreDocumentSupport.aj:47)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.coreGetDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.AxiomDocumentSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_common_AxiomDocumentSupport$org_apache_axiom_om_impl_intf_AxiomDocument$getOMDocumentElement(AxiomDocumentSupport.aj:32)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:1)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:557)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:553)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDefaultDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:230)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:107)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:36)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:666)
    ... 70 more
<May 12, 2017 3:50:29 PM EEST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@181830207[app:kbs_3asd module:kbs_3asd path: spec-version:2.5]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dao.SozMaasDAO.ogrenimDurumRowSelect(SozMaasDAO.java:1198)
    at bus.SozMaasBUS.listYoktenMezunBilgisiGetir(SozMaasBUS.java:7622)
    at bus.SozMaasBUS$$FastClassByCGLIB$$41cbd8aa.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

---

Note:
When I added the web service client, the codes was created in this way

```
webmethods.wsdls.universitebirim.universitebirimv1.UniversiteBirimv1Stub.ıDdenBirimAdiGetir
```

But I changed them like this:

```
webmethods.wsdls.universitebirim.universitebirimv1.UniversiteBirimv1Stub.iDdenBirimAdiGetir
```

Code:

```
public static Birim birimAgaciGetir(long birim_id){
        Birim birim= new Birim();

         try {

             UniversiteBirimv1Stub stub = new UniversiteBirimv1Stub();
             IDdenBirimAdiGetir c2f = new IDdenBirimAdiGetir();
             c2f.setBIRIM_ID(birim_id);
             IDdenBirimAdiGetirE e= new IDdenBirimAdiGetirE();
             e.setIDdenBirimAdiGetir(c2f);
             IDdenBirimAdiGetirResponseE res = stub.ıDdenBirimAdiGetir(e);
             System.out.println("Tested: "+res);
             birim= res.getIDdenBirimAdiGetirResponse().getBirim();


             //System.out.println(res.getIDdenBirimAdiGetirResponse().getBirim().getBAGLI_OLDUGU_BIRIM_ID());
     } catch (AxisFault e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (RemoteException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     }catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
 }
         return birim;

    }
```

I used this in main project.

```
System.out.println(res.getIDdenBirimAdiGetirResponse().getBirim().getBAGLI_OLDUGU_BIRIM_ID());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, added two jars(StAX, Woodstox) in project

Answer (score 0):

In my case the service was down and hence axis2 gave the same error. Once the service started, I was able to invoke and get the response.